When Access restarts, GSSAPI authenticated ODBC connections to PostgreSQL are lost
I have an Access front end which I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database.
I use DSNless connections which I create with the following connect string:
Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode;DATABASE=dbname;SERVER=dbhost.domain.com;PORT=5432;UID=dbusername;CA=r;A7=100;B0=255;B1=8190;BI=0;C2=;D6=-101;CX=1c385508b;A1=7.4-2

The connection works normally. I can use my tables.
If I restart the Access front end, I lose connection to my tables with the following error:
Error: 3151 : ODBC--connection to '{PostgreSQL Unicode} dbhost.domain.com' failed.
Using tabledef.refreshlink doesn't help. I can run the code to remove and relink the tables to make it work again, but this is unsatisfactory.
I noticed that the tabledef.connect now reads:
ODBC;DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=dbname;SERVER=dbhost.domain.com;PORT=5432;CA=r;A7=100;B0=255;B1=8190;BI=0;C2=;D6=-101;CX=1c385508b;A1=7.4-2

The UID (username) is missing. I am wondering if this is the problem, and why it isn't retained in the connect property of the linked tables.
Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I don't supply a password? I am using GSSAPI, which uses the Windows AD via kerberos to actually authenticate the domain user with their Windows username and password automatically. Using this method, you specify which role to connect as, but no password. Your Windows credentials are used to authenticate you and then the specified database role is your name as far as postgres is concerned (there is a map file to link the two).
My working theory is that Access is not storing the UID because there is no password, then fails to connect on restart because there is no UID.
Any thoughts?

Albert D. Kallal as part of this answer provided a function (below) which seems to work around the issue.
It creates a temporary new tabledef with a connection string (I supplied the same one my other code uses, which includes a UID) and then uses it to do a simple select 1 to verify connection. This seems to "pre-populate" the credentials part of the ODBC connection, which isn't saved in the connect property. That makes all the rest of the tables work normally when they are accessed.
I don't remember having to do anything like this in the past. Does anyone know what's changed, or am I just doing something silly?
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon
   
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.'
   ' this does assume user has enough rights to query built in'
   ' system tables'
   
   qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 "
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True
   
   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function

